# ajax - Why onclick doesn't work with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox

I am currently creating tables and checkboxes using ajax communication.

After it was created, it was confirmed that the checkbox function was working normally,
Even if I include checked while creating it, the onclick function doesn't fire.

```
success:function(data){
    for (var key in data) {
        feature = data[key]
        head = feature[0].split(" ")
        tail = feature[1].split(" ")
        type = feature[2]
        name = feature[3]
        $('#pharmacophore_table').append("<tr>" + 
            "<td>" + name + "</td>" +
            "<td> <label><input type='checkbox' name='ligand_feature' onclick='show_ligand_feature(this, " + '"' + feature + '"' + ");' ></label>" + 
            "</tr>");

        $("input[name='ligand_feature']").attr( "checked", true);
    }      
},
error:function(data){
    alert(data.status)
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Those quotes don't look right to me. Does the input render properly in the DOM so the onclick looks right there?

Comment: After creation the onclick function works fine.
The problem is that the onclick function does not work when created and checked with the ajax function.

Comment: Are you expecting the onclick function to be called when you set `checked`?

Comment: Yes I want to enable all checkboxes at the same time as they are created.

Comment: Ok but it's still not clear what isn't working and why. Can you create a demo that reproduces the problem? See [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

Just add click event

```
complete: function(){
    var chck = document.getElementsByName('ligand_feature')
    for (var l=0; l<chck.length; l++){
        chck[l].click();
    }
```